# How would you sort an array in Ruby based off of a formula (e.g. search ranking)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

So, I'm building quick and dirty search functionality in my first rails app.  I'm doing a query and returning a list of objects.  e.g.

```
@articles = Article.find_by_sql("select * from article where title like "%test%" or title like "%foobar%")
```

So, the articles collection will return a lot of data, some of it matching my search terms better than others.  I want to sort the array so that the items that match are presented first.

Here's the conceptual pseudo code I'm trying to implement.

```
for each article in @articles
    calculate the article score based on how many times the search terms appear
sort the array of articles based on the score
```

("score" is not part of the article object.)

Any ideas on how this can be sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all else fails you can do:

```
@articles.sort! {|x,y| search_fitness_function(y) <=> search_fitness_function(x)}
```

Comment: If search_fitness_function is expensive, I'd recommend using sort_by rather than sort.

Comment: Yes. `@articles.sort_by {|a| a.score(term)}`

Comment: I tried it both ways, but get, "Array can't be coerced into Fixnum."

Comment: Nevermind, I had an error in my "score" function.  Works great!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what database you're using it might be more efficient to complete the ranking there.  For instance, in MySQL you could you Natural Language Full Text Search:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

> By default or with the IN NATURAL
>   LANGUAGE MODE modifier, the MATCH()
>   function performs a natural language
>   search for a string against a text
>   collection. A collection is a set of
>   one or more columns included in a
>   FULLTEXT index. The search string is
>   given as the argument to AGAINST().
>   For each row in the table, MATCH()
>   returns a relevance value; that is, a
>   similarity measure between the search
>   string and the text in that row in the
>   columns named in the MATCH() list.